# Which package should I download to compile C++0x code

Tags: 10.04, gcc, g++

OS is Ubuntu 10.04.
I need to compile some C++ code with `-std=c++0x` flag. But compiling doesn't work because I need 4.6.1 version.
Now, when I go to Gnu's ftp, I see two different packages:

```
gcc-4.6.1   
gcc-g++-4.6.1
```

Knowing that I need to compile C++0x code, which one should I download, and how do I install it/them?
I already installed these libraries (gmp, mpc and mpfr).

Comment: Don't install `gcc`, instead, install `g++`

Answer (score 1):

Find yourself a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=gcc) that suits your needs, and install a GCC package from there. There are install instruction within each PPA's page.

Obviously, PPAs contain unofficial packages, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I think this PPA has gcc 4.6.1 : [Toolchain test builds](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test). But the installation process probably will replace other packages. Probably would be safer downloading the source and compiling it yourself.

You can also upgrade to 11.10 or install it in a VM (currently it has gcc/g++ 4.6.1).